# yaml parse in python: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, yaml

I want to parse an yaml file in python. My hosts.yaml file is as below:

```
access:
  host: abc
    hostUrl: url-for-abc
    bearerToken: jjlhlj
    expires: someDate
  host: xyz
    hostUrl: url-for-xyz
    bearerToken: kdsddh
    expires: someDate
```

My python code to parse the yaml is as below:

```
import yaml

def parse():
    with open('hosts.yaml', 'r') as hosts_file:
        hosts = yaml.load(hosts_file)
        for host, val in  hosts["access"]["host"]:
            print host
            print host["hostUrl"]
            print host["bearerToken"]

parse()
```

I am getting the below error:

```
python parse_yaml.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse_yaml.py", line 19, in <module>
    parse()
  File "parse_yaml.py", line 13, in parse2
    hosts = yaml.safe_load(hosts_file)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 93, in safe_load
    return load(stream, SafeLoader)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 71, in load
    return loader.get_single_data()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 37, in get_single_data
    node = self.get_single_node()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 36, in get_single_node
    document = self.compose_document()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 55, in compose_document
    node = self.compose_node(None, None)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 84, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 133, in compose_mapping_node
    item_value = self.compose_node(node, item_key)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 84, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 127, in compose_mapping_node
    while not self.check_event(MappingEndEvent):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 98, in check_event
    self.current_event = self.state()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 428, in parse_block_mapping_key
    if self.check_token(KeyToken):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 116, in check_token
    self.fetch_more_tokens()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 220, in fetch_more_tokens
    return self.fetch_value()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 576, in fetch_value
    self.get_mark())
yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "hosts.yaml", line 3, column 12
```

I am not able to understand, if it is wrong with yaml file structure of some issue with the code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code you run is not the same as the code you displayed. Also, ScannerError isn't a SyntaxError.

Comment: yes...Actually there were some official values in the code. I edited while copying here.

Comment: There is absolutely no need to use PyYAML's `load()`, which is documented to be unsafe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have both a string and an object as the value of a key. You can either do strings

```
access:
  host: abc
  host: xyz
```

or objects

```
access:
  host:
    hostUrl: url-for-abc
    bearerToken: jjlhlj
    expires: someDate
  host:
    hostUrl: url-for-xyz
    bearerToken: kdsddh
    expires: someDate
```

but not both

```
access:
  host: abc
    hostUrl: url-for-abc
    bearerToken: jjlhlj
    expires: someDate
  host: xyz
    hostUrl: url-for-xyz
    bearerToken: kdsddh
    expires: someDate
```

I suggest you put the name of the host in a `name` key in the object

```
access:
  host:
    name: abc
    hostUrl: url-for-abc
    bearerToken: jjlhlj
    expires: someDate
  host:
    name: xyz
    hostUrl: url-for-xyz
    bearerToken: kdsddh
    expires: someDate
```

Comment: Thanks. But, if both are host, how can I iterate over it to get the values of nested nodes (name, expires etc)?

Comment: That is a different question altogether.